# Authorization Issue with JWT token creation Method (User Roles)

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, jwt, postman

Below I have a working JWT token creation method which will work without the authorization tag at the top of the method. I have also created User Roles which was working before I previously implemented the token. I believe that since the token implementation method I have been unable to configure Authorization by role and instead the code thinks that any authorization requires the JWT token. When I pass the token into postman the authentication will work under simple `[Authorize]`. But I need the create token method to be restricted so that only registered users can use it.

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Users")]
        [HttpPost("api/auth/token")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateToken([FromBody]
        CredentialViewModel model)
        {

            try
            {
                var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (_hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, user.PasswordHash, model.Password) == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
                    {
                        // Get the claims from the user
                        var userClaims = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

                        var claims = new[] {
              new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
              new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, user.APIKey.ToString()),
              new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email??"")
            }.Union(userClaims);

                        //*********************************

                        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]));
                        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);


                        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                          issuer: _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
                          audience: _config["Tokens:Audience"],
                          claims: claims,
                          expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10),
                          signingCredentials: creds
                          );


                        return Ok(new
                        {
                            token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                            expiration = token.ValidTo

                        });

                    }

                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                _logger.LogError($"Exception thrown while creating JWT: {ex}");
            }

            return BadRequest();

        }
```

example json input

```
{
    "username" : "user02",
    "password" : "test123"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the **RoleClaimType** value properly where you verify the JWT tokens, or in your Startup.cs file.

```
using System.Security.Claims;
```

....

```
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
  ......
  .....
  RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role
};
```